# Falta imagen en Intent al recibir datos simples de otras apps en Android

Tags: android, android-studio, android-intent

He preparado mi app para que pueda recibir datos simples de otras apps, tal como se describe en https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/receive?hl=es-419. El objetivo es que, cuando quiera compartir un contenido desde Instagram, Chrome o desde donde sea, mi app aparezca en la lista de abajo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En el AndroidManifest.xml he añadido las siguientes líneas, asociadas a MyActivity, que es donde gestiono el correspondiente Intent con el contenido compartido desde otras apps:

```
<activity android:name=".ui.MyActivity" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND_MULTIPLE" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Después, en MyActivity recibo y gestiono el Intent:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    ...
    when {
        intent?.action == Intent.ACTION_SEND -> {
            if ("text/plain" == intent.type) {
                handleSendText(intent) // Handle text being sent
            } else if (intent.type?.startsWith("image/") == true) {
                handleSendImage(intent) // Handle single image being sent
            }
        }
        intent?.action == Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE
                && intent.type?.startsWith("image/") == true -> {
                handleSendMultipleImages(intent) // Handle multiple images being sent
        }
        else -> {
            // Handle other intents, such as being started from the home screen
        }
    }
    ...
}

private fun handleSendText(intent: Intent) {
    intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT)?.let {
        // Update UI to reflect text being shared
        ...
    }
}

private fun handleSendImage(intent: Intent) {
    (intent.getParcelableExtra<Parcelable>(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM) as? Uri)?.let {
        // Update UI to reflect image being shared
        ...
    }
}

private fun handleSendMultipleImages(intent: Intent) {
    intent.getParcelableArrayListExtra<Parcelable>(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM)?.let {
        // Update UI to reflect multiple images being shared
        ...
    }
}
```

El invento funciona hasta cierto punto, y es que no consigo localizar la información de la imagen en ninguno de los ejemplos con los que he probado. Es decir, nunca me llega nada en `intent.getParcelableExtra<Parcelable>(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM)`.

He leído que la información de la imagen no siempre va a llegar en estos Intents, pero he probado, por ejemplo, a compartir https://es.ign.com/the-legend-of-zelda-breath-of-the-wild-2/190693/review/analisis-de-the-legend-of-zelda-tears-of-the-kingdom-la-culminacion-de-breath-of-the-wild a WhatsApp y ahí sí que veo esa imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero si comparto ese mismo enlace desde mi app, como digo, el Intent no parece contener esa imagen.

¿Alguna idea?

Answer (score 2):

Las tarjetas que se generan al compartir, se muestran con base en meta datos llamados "Open Graph Meta Tags", estos meta datos se agregan en el  de la página html y al compartir se genera automáticamente la tarjeta.

La información de la imagen o url del recurso a compartir no viene al realizar un intent.

Al analizar la página de la cual requieres obtener la imagen se tienen los siguientes metadatos para las siguientes redes sociales:

```
 <!-- HTML Meta Tags -->
  <title>Análisis de The Legend of Zelda: Tears of the Kingdom, la culminación de Breath of the Wild</title>
  <meta name="description" content="El Zelda del héroe forjado">

<!-- WhatsApp Meta Tags -->
  <meta property="og:title" content="Análisis de The Legend of Zelda: Tears of the Kingdom, la culminación de Breath of the Wild">
  <meta property="og:description" content="El Zelda del héroe forjado">
  <meta property="og:url" content="https://es.ign.com/the-legend-of-zelda-breath-of-the-wild-2/190693/review/analisis-de-the-legend-of-zelda-tears-of-the-kingdom-la-culminacion-de-breath-of-the-wild">
  <meta property="og:image" content="https://sm.ign.com/t/ign_es/screenshot/default/keyart-desktop-3_91nb.1200.jpg">

  <!-- Facebook Meta Tags -->
  <meta property="og:url" content="https://es.ign.com/the-legend-of-zelda-breath-of-the-wild-2/190693/review/analisis-de-the-legend-of-zelda-tears-of-the-kingdom-la-culminacion-de-breath-of-the-wild">
  <meta property="og:type" content="website">
  <meta property="og:title" content="Análisis de The Legend of Zelda: Tears of the Kingdom, la culminación de Breath of the Wild">
  <meta property="og:description" content="El Zelda del héroe forjado">
  <meta property="og:image" content="https://sm.ign.com/t/ign_es/screenshot/default/keyart-desktop-3_91nb.1200.jpg">

  <!-- Twitter Meta Tags -->
  <meta name="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image">
  <meta property="twitter:domain" content="es.ign.com">
  <meta property="twitter:url" content="https://es.ign.com/the-legend-of-zelda-breath-of-the-wild-2/190693/review/analisis-de-the-legend-of-zelda-tears-of-the-kingdom-la-culminacion-de-breath-of-the-wild">
  <meta name="twitter:title" content="Análisis de The Legend of Zelda: Tears of the Kingdom, la culminación de Breath of the Wild">
  <meta name="twitter:description" content="El Zelda del héroe forjado">
  <meta name="twitter:image" content="https://sm.ign.com/t/ign_es/screenshot/default/keyart-desktop-3_91nb.1200.jpg">
```

La única solución para obtener la imagen definida en estos metadatos es parsear el html de la página a cargar, incluso usando JSoup sería de gran ayuda, revisa:

[Parsing Open Graph meta](https://gist.github.com/anandwana001/57cf460abbf401c41ca65e7009f5457c)

Answer (score 1):

Me respondo a mí mismo: esa imagen que buscaba no viene en el Intent. Hay que buscarla en el código HTML de la página, dentro de los metadatos. Una forma sencilla es usar la librería [jsoup](https://jsoup.org/):

```
// Metadatos que necesito extraer.
data class HtmlMetadata(
    val siteName: String?,
    val title: String?,
    val description: String?,
    val fullUrl: String?,
    val shortUrl: String?,
    val previewImageUrl: String?
)

// Función que extrae los metadatos.
fun getMetadata(url: String?): HtmlMetadata {
    Jsoup.connect(url).get().also { document ->
        return HtmlMetadata(
            siteName = document.getContent("og:site_name"),
            title = document.getContent("og:title"),
            description = document.getContent("og:description"),
            fullUrl = document.getContent("og:url"),
            shortUrl = Uri.parse(document.getContent("og:url"))?.host,
            previewImageUrl = document.getContent("og:image")
        )
    }
}

private fun Document.getContent(propertyName: String): String? {
    this.select("meta[property=$propertyName]").also { property ->
        return if (!property.isNullOrEmpty()) {
            property.first().attr("content")
        } else {
            null
        }
    }
}
```